# Updating a rails attribute through a model association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

I have two models `shop` and `user`.  Shop `has_many` Users and User `has_one` Shop.  I'm trying to create a button on `shop/show` that allows a user to choose its shop.  The button should send the parameter `shop_id` to `Users_Controller#update_shop` which then changes `User.shop_id` to the id of the shop on the page.

The current method in `Users_Controller#update_shop` is the following:

```
def update_shop
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @user.update_attributes(shop_id: params[:shop][:id])
  flash[:success] = "Added Shop!"
end
```

And the button on `show/shop` is this:

```
  <%= form_for User.update_shop, remote: true do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :shop_id, value: @shop.id %>
    <%= f.submit 'Add As Your Shop', :class => 'button blue-button' %>
  <% end %>
```

I'm getting the error `NoMethodError in ShopsController#show undefined method`update_shop' for #`.  The method is defined in the Users controller though.

I understand there is probably a more efficient way to update `User.shop_id` through the association, so tips on doing that or getting this to work are greatly appreciated.

Comment: It should be  `User belongs_to Shop`, not `has_one`

Comment: `User.update_shop` is wrong. It should be the controller action url or a object. Not the one you tried.

Comment: @ArupRakshit I'm trying to make it go to the method `Users_Controller#update_shop`, what would the controller action url/object be in that case then?

Comment: first you have to change has_one to belongs_to. And second check update_shop method, here you are considering params[:shop][:id] while from  here <%= f.hidden_field :shop_id, value: @shop.id %> you are sending shop_id.

Comment: apart from your form being invalid, as mentioned above, it's also vulnerable to hack, I can just go into page code and set the shop.id to whatever value I want and in your controller it would be processed and assigned successfully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's better to have a link with POST method in place of form:

```
<%= link_to 'Add As Your Shop', update_shop_url(id: @user.id, shop_id: @shop.id, class: 'button blue-button', data: { method: 'post' } %>
```

With this setup you should change controller method as well:

```
def update_shop
  ...
  @user.update_attributes(shop_id: params[:shop_id])
  ...
end
```

Comment: I think this is the way to go.  I'm still getting `NoMethodError in ShopsController#show undefined method 'id' for nil:NilClass` on the `link_to` button line.  I created a route `post 'updateshop' => 'users#update_shop', as: 'update_shop_url'`, how can I stop this error?

Comment: Do you have both `@user` and `@shop` models defined? The `@user` is the current user, I suppose?

Comment: That worked.  Now I get `undefined method `update_shop'` on the link in the form.  This has a route as shown in my first comment, why won't that work?

Comment: You should define route like this: `post 'updateshop' => 'users#update_shop', as: 'update_shop'`, and call the url as `update_shop_url`

Comment: Clicking the button gives me `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/updateshop")` but the `link_to` specifies is a post and the `update_shop_url` is a POST.  Why is this happening? Thanks for your help with the followup errors.

Comment: Did you add `data: { method: 'post' }`  in the end of `link_to`? You are sending GET request instead of POST.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88356/discussion-between-virge-assault-and-dimakura).